# Using GRPC instead of WCF in CefSharp for .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I need to use JavaScript binding in .net core, but it doesn't support WCF. Is there any way to use GRPC instead of WCF?

Comment: Only through gRPC-Web. Web browsers don't support gRPC itself and Chromium is no exception. `I need to use JavaScript binding in .net core, but it doesn't support WCF.` what does that mean? What `JavaScript binding`? What isn't working? WCF is primarily used for SOAP services, which is just HTTP. You can write `fetch` just fine, but you'll have to create the correct XML request and parse the XML response

Comment: Async JavaScript Binding is supported in .Net Core. No plans to port the WCF synchronous implementation to grpc. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#async-javascript-binding-jsb

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

At the moment I have no plans to add support for the synchronous JavaScript Binding implementation to .Net Core/5/6.

You can use the asynchronous JavaScript Binding implementation which uses chromium native IPC.